# Reset/Refesh UIscroll view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, reset, subview

I Have a scroll view that contains multiple view controllers. On those view controllers I have switches. When on switch is "on" all the other switches turn off. This is all done through the `viewDidLoad`.

I cannot get this to work though, I have tried putting the code for the switch thingy stuff that I am trying to do in `viewWillAppear`. It seems though that these two methods are only called at run time.

My alternative idea is to somehow "reset" the scroll view from inside one of the subviews

here is what i have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(vc0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
    vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle:nil)

    var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
    vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle:nil)

    var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    vc2.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let vc3 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle:nil)

    var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
    frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
    vc3.view.frame = frame3

    self.addChildViewController(vc3)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc3.view)
    vc3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height - 66);
 }
}
```

^for the scrollUI creator class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController0: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var onoff: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    onoff.on = false

}

@IBAction func used(sender: AnyObject) {
    let parent = self.view.superview
       parent?.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

^this is one of the subclasses

This subclass has a switch and when toggled, it should "reset" the scroll view so all of the subviews `viewDidLoad` are called again...

This does not work.... Are there any solutions to this??

BTW sorry for the bad formatting for the code blocks.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to accomplish… but can you use a page view controller instead?

Comment: If you want to call a method at some specific time, just make it its own method and call it… don't try to force iOS to call viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc. at weird times

Comment: @AaronBrager here is the problem I have, I have multiple views that all have switches. Only on switch can be turned on at a time. I have an algorithm that makes sure that the switch is on and the others are off. This is all done through viewDidLoad. The problem with pageview controller and UIscroll view is that those things only call all of the contained viewcontrollers's viewdidload once. The way that I was able to get around was when the switch is toggled, to have the button check the algorithm (which is in a singleton)  but this causes the switch to be toggled twice to update it

Comment: Well stop putting things in viewDidLoad if you'll need to call them again later :)

Comment: @AaronBrager is there a way to change the state of a switch in another class? or is that not possible ( the IBoutlet of a switch is in another class, and from a different class how would I switch the state of it)

Comment: Sure. Right now `vc0`, `vc1`, etc. go out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad` so you lose the references, but if you save them as properties then you can change a switch like `vc0.onoff.isOn = true`

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks for the responses, just picked up swift a couple days ago, so uhh, how would I make them "properties"? and how would I access them from subviews?

Comment: You should read [the docs on properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) (you want a "stored property" for this case). From the subviews, there are many approaches; I would use [delegation](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) with `ViewController` as the delegate and the sub-viewcontrollers as delegators.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks so much!!!!!